# Determinant of the Jacobian of a short map

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, lipschitz-functions, jacobian

Let $U\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ and $f:U\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ be an everywhere differentiable short map (i.e. a Lipschitz function with upper Lipschitz constant =1, the upper Lipschitz constant is defined as $\sup\limits_{x\in U}\sup\limits_{v\in\mathbb{R}^2,||v||=1}||df_xv||$). Suppose that $f$ is also bi-Lipschitz and that its lower Lipschitz constant is equal to $c$, $0<c<1$ (the lower Lipschitz constant is defined as $\inf\limits_{x\in U}\inf\limits_{v\in\mathbb{R}^2,||v||=1}||df_xv||$).

Let $|J_f(p)|$ be the determinant of the Jacobian of $f$ in $p\in U$.

In this case I've read that it should be $|J_f(p)|\ge c$ for every $p\in U$, but I can't understand why. Can you explain it to me?

Comment: So you're assuming $f$ is differentiable everywhere in $U?$

Comment: yes, I'll add it

Comment: Also  "and that its lower Lipschitz constant ..." is missing a clause.

Comment: now everything should be ok

Comment: What if $f(x) = (1/2)x?$

Comment: it is not a function from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: Yes it is, you used $x$ as in $\mathbb R^2.$ Think of it as $x = (x_1,x_2).$

Comment: I see, then its Lipschitz constant is $1/2$, not 1.

Comment: Lower L. constant is $1/2$ but the Jacobian has determinant $1/4.$

Comment: Apparently I didn't make myself clear. By Lipschitz constant I mean the upper Lipschitz constant, which must be equal to 1. Your function has upper Lipschitz constant equal to $1/2$

Comment: Its upper and lower L.constants are the same, $1/2.$

Comment: Yes, but as it's clear in the question I only consider functions with upper Lipschitz constant equal to 1

Comment: Yes, you're right. Sorry, my bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:** The argument below shows that pointwise the Jacobian determinant is the product of the upper and lower local Lipschitz constants, but that actually does not quite adress the question.

With the definitions and assumptions given, the conclusion is wrong, the best lower bound for the Jacobian determinant is $c^2$. One simple counterexample to the stated conclusion is given by the conformal map $f(z) = e^z$ where $U = [-1,0] \times [0,\pi]$ (and where $\mathbb{R}^2$ is identified with the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$ in the usual way.) Pointwise upper and lower Lipschitz constants are $|f'(z)| = |e^z| = e^x$, which has maximum $1$ and minimum $1/e$ in $U$. The Jacobian determinant is $|f'(z)|^2 = e^{2x}$ which has minimum $1/e^2$ in $U$.

---

The way you defined the upper and lower Lipschitz constants is not standard, typically they are the optimal positive constants $c$ and $C$ such that $c|x-y| \le |f(x)-f(y)| \le C|x-y|$. However, going with your definition this is basically just a local result which comes down to linear algebra. For fixed $p$ with $A = df_p$, the directional derivative in the direction $v$ with $\| v \|=1$ is just $Av$, and the maximal and minimal norms of these are the maximal and minimal singular values of $A$, i.e., the square roots of the maximal and minimal eigenvalues of $A^t A$. In your case where the dimension is $2$ there are just two eigenvalues, and the determinant is the product of those, so under your assumptions $\det A^t A = c^2$, so the Jacobian determinant is $\det A = \pm c$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but there is a point I don't understand. I get that $det(df_p)=c_pC_p$ where $c_p$ and $C_p$ are the minimal and maximal singular values of $df_p$ and $C_p\le C$, $c_p\ge c$ where c is the lower Lipschitz constant and $C$ is the upper Lipschitz constant. But if $C_p<1$ then it follows $c_p^2\le det(df_p)<c_p$ which doesn't imply $det(df_p)\ge c$. Is it because it's always $C_p\ge 1$?

Comment: @user00169: Actually, $c_p$ and $C_p$ are the lower and upper Lipschitz constants, not just bounds for those. Also, in the comments above you made clear that you assume that the upper Lipschitz constant is equal to one, not less than one. (Otherwise, the conclusion is false, as also pointed out in the comments above.)

Comment: @LucasGeyer Thank you again for your response. Then it's clear to me that I don't get why is it that the maximal and minimal singular values of $df_p$ (call them respectively $C_p$ and $c_p$) are respectively the upper and lower Lipschitz constants for any point $p\in U$. Shouldn't it be $C_p=\sup\limits_{||v||=1}||df_pv||$ and $c_p=\inf\limits_{||v||=1}||df_pv||$? Instead it is $C=\sup\limits_{p\in U}\sup\limits_{||v||=1}||df_pv||$ and $c=\inf\limits_{p\in U}\sup\limits_{||v||=1}||df_pv||$. Could you please explain to me what am I getting wrong?

Comment: sorry, in my last comment I meant $c=\inf\limits_{p\in U}\inf\limits_{||v||=1}||df_pv||$

Comment: @user00169: Oh, sorry, now I see what you mean, I somehow misread the definition. With this definition the conclusion is wrong, you will only get a lower bound of $c^2$.